# Java Natie access: Class not registered

Tags: java, jna

I am trying to use jna, I have setup jna and jna-platform, I use maven:

```html
 <dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I got this error:

```js
com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.COMException: Класс не зарегистрирован(HRESULT: 80040154)
```

It says, COMException: class is not registered,

I have no idea how to register that class. Basically project builds ok.

EDIT: 
This is where the error is thrown:

```js
 MassaKDrv massaKDrv = factory.createObject(MassaKDrv.class);
```

And here is my MassaKDrv class

```js
package some_package_name;

import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.util.IUnknown;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.util.annotation.ComObject;
                    
@ComObject(clsId = "{some id}")
public interface MassaKDrv extends IUnknown {
    
}
```

So, I guess I have to register by MassaKDrv object somewhere

Comment: Can you share the code from where this error is getting trowed

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri, I edited my post accordingly